# Plumbing espresso machine filter to wall water outlet meant for ice maker

Tags: plumbing, ice-maker, water-filtration

I am trying to plumb my 1/8" BSPT espresso machine through a water filter with both 3/8" FNPT inlet and outlet into the water outlet behind my refrigerator. So far, I have a 1/8" BSPT to 3/8" NPT adapter, and I have ordered a stainless 3/8" M to 3/8" M coupler/nipple. I believe this should cover everything from the filter outlet to the machine. You can see this part (minus the nipple/coupler) on the right hand side of the filter.

[image]

The problem I have now is trying to find a suitable connection from the water outlet. I believe the outlet has a 1/8" fitting, but am not sure what standard this is. As seen in the above picture in the bottom left, there was some kind of compression fitting on it. The outlet measures ~.44" OD as measured from the wall, and the compression nut measures ~.39" ID as seen in the picture above. The outlet itself comes off a shutoff valve. The shutoff valve body has a 1/2" M brass pipe fitting that threads directly into the wall.

[image]

So my question is what is the best way to connect the water filter inlet to the wall water outlet. I am willing to replace the shutoff valve with something different if it makes sense. This is all going to be used for potable water, so something with no brass would be even better. I tried going to the hardware store, and they didn't have any solution as the water filter inlet is 3/8" FNPT and all their shutoff valves used compression fittings which were a different size.

Answer (score 1):

The local big box and hardware stores here carry 1/4 compression to 1/2 FIP adapters, 1/2 MIP nipples, and 1/2 FIP to 3/4 MIP nipples, all in lead-free brass. If I were faced with this problem, I would pick up a 1/4 compression ice maker supply line and the other three fittings, and use that to adapt all the way from the pictured fitting to your 3/4 filter. Lead free brass is safe for potable water use.

Late edit: I realized you said 3/8 and I somehow read it as 3/4. For 3/8 it's even easier, as they stock 1/4 compression to 3/8 MIP fittings, again in lead-free brass. A single fitting and a 1/4 compression supply line would have this hooked up in a jiffy.

The part I forgot to mention: ice maker supply lines are usually 1/4 compression.